# Adding Scale bar to ImageJ / FIJI manually from metadeta

Tags: imagej

How can I add a scale bar to Tif images? the metadeta I have is in the form of tif.anx, tif.eax and XML file.  I don't understand how to add it to my image so that I can get a scale Bar.

The XML file is in the following link https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcnjzgb01mlrrxj/image46.tif.cal.xml

ANX file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wal7e1a7mxqwwde/image46.tif.anx

Comment: Show us what code you have so far, and we can help you with what you're missing.

Comment: I've added links to the XML and ANX files

Answer (score 1):

According to [this ticket](http://trac.openmicroscopy.org.uk/ome/ticket/4179), support for the Leica Stereo Microscope format by [Bio-Formats](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/products/bio-formats) is planned but not yet available.

However, your file `image46.tif.anx` contains the lines:

```xml
<Calibration>
    <Units>mm</Units>
    <MetresPerPixel>1E-06</MetresPerPixel>
</Calibration>
```

so after opening the plain tif file in Fiji, you can set the scale calibration manually via the [*Image > Properties...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub%3aImage%3EProperties...) dialog, or using macro code:

```bsh
run("Properties...", "unit=mm pixel_width=1E-03 pixel_height=1E-03");
```

alternatively, in Java or Javascript:

```js
IJ.run(imp, "Properties...", "unit=mm pixel_width=1E-03 pixel_height=1E-03");
```

Then, you can add a scale bar via [*Analyze > Tools > Scale Bar...*](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub%3aScale-Bar...), or via following example macro code:

```bsh
run("Scale Bar...", "width=0.1 height=4 font=14 color=White background=None location=[Lower Right] bold overlay");
```